# How to remove the largest element in the array along with the elements to the right of it in Python 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, recursion, range, max

I want to remove the largest element in the array along with the elements to right of it

Here is my code:

```
>>> curG = [34,89,11,99,36,92,67]
>>> f = curG.index(max(curG))
>>> for i in range(f,len(curG)):
       curG.remove(curG[i])
```

I want to do this recursively till there is no more element in the array, that is till len(curG)==0.

But the error that occurs with this program is only the largest element is removed in the first pass, but the elements to the right of it continue to remain in the array.
Also the program throws an error like this:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're up to this but I won't judge. You could do it with a `while` loop more easily, providing a slice to `del` instead of continuously calling `.remove` on the list:

```
while len(curG):
    del curG[curG.index(max(curG)):]
    # print(curG)
```

If you print each element (uncomment the `print` call) the results are:

```
[34, 89, 11]
[34]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are mutating the array that you are looping over (so the length of the list is shorter as you go through your for loop). I think an easier way of achieving this is to do:

```
curG = curG[0:curG.index(max(curG))]
```